# Detecting if an object reached target points

Tags: algorithms, python, robotics

I have an object that is moving towards target points and I want to determine when it will reach or pass through them. I receive points in real time, which represent the current position of the object. The position is a 6-D vector. The data can be download from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13IWiQjl2UgltGrv71ZCXMIedOxYGoNHa/view?usp=sharing)

**Initial approach**

For each received point:

- Calculate distance between current and target points.
- As the object approaches the target, the distance decreases. If current distance is greater than previous distance, I consider that it has reached the target. It's good enough for me.

**Problem**

The problem is that the point can sometimes fluctuate a bit. It can increase and then decrease again (noise), even if it has not yet reached the target. But because of this fluctuation, my algorithm detects a false positive because the current distance is greater than the previous one.

The image shows false positives and true positives. When a real upward trend begins, I know that the object has reached the target point. My simple idea to start with is to get rid of false positives by using a smoothing filter and fit a curve. After that I can find when positive slope begins which tells me when object reached target.

I wonder if I should try this approach or any other recommendations including smoothing filters, fitting a curve, etc?

[image]

Comment: Please confirm if this is a 1D problem. (In 2D, the distance can form a minimum while being far from the origin.)

Comment: If 1D, why don't you just compare the distance to $0$ ? Or detect a change of sign ?

Comment: I suggest you show us one or two examples of real data: a plot of the sequence of points (connected by lines) in 1D, 2D, or 3D; a plot of the distance from the origin, as a function of time.  Also, what do you know about the movement of the object?  Does it tend to move in a straight line?  Is it a physical object, with acceleration typically bounded (e.g., a car, a plane, etc.)?  I don't think we can answer whether you should use noise filters; that will depend on the specific situation where this arises, and is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @D.W., I added an update in my post

Comment: Please don't use "UPDATE".  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/657/is-there-ever-any-point-in-adding-edit-to-a-question-or-answer

Comment: I'll renew my suggestion that you include a plot of the data points themselves, in addition to your plot of distance from the origin as a function of time.  Please use the same dataset for both.

Comment: @D.W., I revised the post and included link to the data. The archive contains the collected positions and target positions

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Can the downvote be removed now that I updated the post?

Comment: You did not answer my first question.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you what will be best; you'll have to try different approaches and see what works best in your setting.

I think one reasonable approach worth trying is to filter the data using a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), then find the filtered point that is closest to the origin (or target) (without trying to look for upward/downward trends).